# How does Einstein's theory of relativity prove Newton's laws of gravitation (or is it incorrect)?

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, speed-of-light, approximations

I have heard that at the speed of light the Newton's laws of gravitation stop working. Why does that happen or does that even happen? Is there any proof to it? From what I have heard It's related to relative mass, but I don't really understand it... So please explain.

Comment: Because it has better agreement with experiment.

Comment: Mathematical proof is not physics. The universe gives us phenomena, not axioms.

Comment: @ConnorBehan That's a "trust us" answer unless you are prepared to say which experiment. See my answer below for four examples.

Comment: More on [Newton gravity and GR](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/newtonian-gravity+general-relativity).

Answer (score 2):

Einstein's theory of general relativity, which describes gravity, gives different predictions for the motions of objects than does Newtonian gravity. The predictions are very different if gravity is strong, but the differences become small in the "weak-field limit."

The example which Einstein gave in 1915 was the orbit of Mercury. Mercury's orbit around the Sun is an ellipse, and the long axis of this ellipse points in some particular direction relative to the distant stars. This direction is not quite constant in time, but instead changes ("precesses") over many orbits. Part of the precession is due to three-body interactions between Mercury, the Sun, and the more distant planets, especially Venus (the nearest) and Jupiter (the heaviest). But part of the precession is unexplained by Newtonian physics. The discrepancy is very small: about one degree every 9000 years. At one point this extra precession was taken as a prediction of a planet orbiting interior to Mercury, which was even given a name, Vulcan. But no astronomers were ever able to spot Vulcan. Einstein's relativity explained that Mercury's extra precession is actually a feature of the two-body interaction between Mercury and the Sun. No hidden planet was needed.

The first "strong-field" evidence which favored general relativity over classical gravity was the [Hulse-Taylor binary pulsar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_pulsar), which exhibits time-dilation effects over the course of each orbit, and whose decaying orbit is exactly consistent with the emission of gravitational waves. More recently, gravitational waves have been observed directly by LIGO and similar observatories. There is no prediction of gravitational radiation in Newtonian gravity.  In Newtonian gravity, a two-body system will have the same orbital characteristics forever.

My favorite example is the position of Earth's Moon. The Newtonian and Einsteinian predictions for the Moon's orbit around Earth are different by about ten meters. This is a twenty-five parts per billion correction, very small.  However, the manned missions to the Moon in the 1970s included the installation of retroreflecting mirrors. In the mid-aughts, laser technology has become advanced enough that very brief pulses of laser light could be directed at these mirrors, and their reflections reliably detected and timed. These "laser lunar ranging" experiments were able to measure the Earth-Moon distance with a precision of a couple of centimeters. The results are consistent with the Einsteinian prediction of the Earth-Moon distance, and inconsistent with the Newtonian distance.